# "Too Many Request" error from LinkedIn in rails

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a developer account and I am receiving the message "Resource level throttle APPLICATION_AND_MEMBER DAY limit for calls to this resource is reached" after making 3-4 requests to the user fetch post endpoint. How can I increase this limitation?

Can we increase this limitation?